# Reallocating 2d char array in c

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, free, realloc

I have a problem with reallocating an array. I want to save inputs to a string array and realloc it with every new entry.
 Heres my function:

```
char** history=0;

int historycounter=0;

void saveHistory(char* input){

    history=(char**)realloc(history,sizeof(*history)+sizeof(input)*sizeof(char));
    history[historycounter]=(char*)malloc(sizeof(input)*sizeof(char));
    strcpy(history[historycounter],input);
    historycounter++;
}
```

Comment: Please format your code. It greatly improves the odds that someone will come help.

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: it's  realloc(): invalid next size: 0x08e5c028

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
void saveHistory(const char *input){
    size_t size = strlen(input)+1;
    history = realloc(history, sizeof(*history)*(historycounter+1));
    history[historycounter] = malloc(size);
    memcpy(history[historycounter], input, size);
    historycounter++;
}
```